# Searching and deleting the Data in python

Tags: python

I have two files which have a list of sites in them. The master file is called A.txt and the processed file is called B.txt

Contents of A.txt

```
www.cnn.com
www.google.com
www.gmail.com
www.iamvishal.com
```

Contents of B.txt

```
www.cnn.com
www.google.com
```

I want to make a python script which compares or searches between the files and creates a new.txt which only has sites from A.txt which have not yet appeared in B.txt

As I am new I did a lot of reading on  this site and found some great examples. 
I have managed to get the work done but I am afraid my logic is wrong.  Pls see the below code:

```
processedfile = open("b.txt")
masterfile = open("a.txt")
f=open("new.txt","w")

for line in processedfile.readlines():
  line = line.strip()
  print line;
  print "We are printing the processed part"
  for linetwo in masterfile.readlines():
     linetwo= linetwo.strip()
     print linetwo
     print "we are printing the master part"
     if linetwo != line:
            f.write(linetwo+"\n")
```

So the new file new.txt contains all the sites which were in A.txt but which were not in B.txt expect the first entry. I am also afraid that there are other logical buts as I have kept B.txt in the same sequence as A.txt so the  the code can easily break if the sites are not in sequence.

Contents of new.txt

```
www.google.com
www.gmail.com
www.iamvishal.com
```

Please advice how should I go about it now as I am confused.

Comment: How about sorting the files and using `comm -23 a.txt b.txt` from the command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = set(open("a.txt"))
b = set(open("b.txt"))
new = open("new.txt", "w")
new.write("".join(a - b))
```

Comment: +1 for conciseness; although this doesn't work correctly because of trailing new lines

Comment: @NullUserException:  I know about the new lines, but since every line has a new-line character, I decided to keep them -- that's why I don't need to re-add them in the final `join()`.  Of course this is a bit fragile in case the last line of some file is lacking a new-line character.

Comment: @user976847 - Read the [python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/) and [dive into python](http://diveintopython.nfshost.com/toc/index.html), so you can learn more about how to use the different data types in Python.

Answer (score 3):

Read the files into two `set`s and use set difference. eg:

```
a = set(line.strip() for line in open('a.txt', 'r'))
b = set(line.strip() for line in open('b.txt', 'r'))

new = open('new.txt', 'w')
new.write('\n'.join(a - b))
```

Comment: +1, I was asked a similar question in an interview before -  I used sets but in C++.

Comment: @birryree what a great comment to add. Give people a reason to learn it for their own future.

Comment: The above code isn't working.  It will only read the first line from each file.

Answer (score 2):

If the files are small, you could use sets to simplify the code:

```
master = set(line.strip() for line in open('a.txt'))
processed = set(line.strip() for line in open('b.txt'))
for name in master - processed:
  print name
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a library in Python called difflib that can do a lot of this work for you. Here is an example of using it:

```
# find the difference between two texts
# tested with Python24   vegaseat  6/2/2005

import difflib

text1 = """The World's Shortest Books:
Human Rights Advances in China
"My Plan to Find the Real Killers" by OJ Simpson
"Strom Thurmond:  Intelligent Quotes"
America's Most Popular Lawyers
Career Opportunities for History Majors
Different Ways to Spell "Bob"
Dr. Kevorkian's Collection of Motivational Speeches
Spotted Owl Recipes by the EPA
The Engineer's Guide to Fashion
Ralph Nader's List of Pleasures
"""

text2 = """The World's Shortest Books:
Human Rights Advances in China
"My Plan to Find the Real Killers" by OJ Simpson
"Strom Thurmond:  Intelligent Quotes"
America's Most Popular Lawyers
Career Opportunities for History Majors
Different Ways to Sell "Bob"
Dr. Kevorkian's Collection of Motivational Speeches
Spotted Owl Recipes by the EPA
The Engineer's Guide to Passion
Ralph Nader's List of Pleasures
"""

# create a list of lines in text1
text1Lines = text1.splitlines(1)
print "Lines of text1:"
for line in text1Lines:
  print line,

print

# dito for text2
text2Lines = text2.splitlines(1)
print "Lines of text2:"
for line in text2Lines:
  print line,

print  

diffInstance = difflib.Differ()
diffList = list(diffInstance.compare(text1Lines, text2Lines))

print '-'*50
print "Lines different in text1 from text2:"
for line in diffList:
  if line[0] == '-':
    print line,
```

Source:
http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/threads/96638